# Parsing XML turns up an empty list (Python)

Tags: python, xml, list, findall

I'm using the code below to extract a number from the XML data beneath the code. For some reason my list however turns up empty. Sorry if the code is a bit messy. It is a work in progress and I was trying some print function to try to get a result. As I do get "Retrieved, len(xmldata), 'characters', I believe the problem lies somewhere around here:

```
pydata = ET.fromstring(xmldata)
```

If I print

```
print (pydata)
```

I get only this:

```
<Element 'commentinfo' at 0x00000075968A7BD8>
```

I think I am missing something quite small, but I am not figuring it out.

```
# Note - I am using Python 3.6
# exec(open("./trial.py").read())
# http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_263475.xml

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import urllib.request
sumcount = 0

while True:
    url = input('Enter url:')
    url = 'http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_263475.xml'
    if len(url) < 1 : break
    print ('Retrieving', url)
    uh = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    xmldata = uh.read()
    print ('Retrieved',len(xmldata),'characters')
    pydata = ET.fromstring(xmldata)
    print('Name:', pydata.find('name'))
    print('Attr:', pydata.find('comment'))
    lst = pydata.findall('comment')
    print (lst)
    print('Count:', len(lst))
    if True : break
```

This is the XML:

```
#<comment>
#  <name>Matthias</name>
#  <count>97</count>
#</comment>
```

Any help would be extremely welcome!

Comment: why do you ask for the url and then immediately over write it?

Comment: Because I don't want to continuously add it while testing. I will eventually remove the overwrite.

Comment: Actual `xml` data structure is not the same as example given in the question. You can use [`XPath expression`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xpath-support) to search the `comment` node, e.g. `lst = pydata.findall('./comments/comment')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read the docs more carefully.

```
Element.findall() finds only elements with a tag which are direct children of the current element
```

If you type `pydata` it will return you this:

```
>><Element 'comment' at 0x10411c090>
```

None of the elements underneath your root element have the tag `comment`, and this is easily verified by doing this:

```
for child in pydata:
    print child.tag

>> name 
   count
```

Also doesn't look like you are printing the actual text value of the elements, so change these lines:

```
print('Name:', pydata.find('name'))
print('Attr:', pydata.find('comment'))
```

To this:

```
print('Name:', pydata.find('name').text)
print('Attr:', pydata.find('comment').text)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I didn't know about the direct children "limitation". The second part I initially had, but I got error messages about it, probably because it was not searching what I thought it was searching.

Comment: if the answer helped you answer the question or answered your question, please accept so that future viewers will see as well.

Comment: How do I accept this exactly? My votes do not seem to count because of my reputation..

Answer (score 0):

After a little trial and error based on your suggestions, I figured out the solution. The final code was supposed to extract the number from the XML code and sum it. If you have any suggestions on how to improve my code, please let me know!

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import urllib.request
sumcount = 0

while True:
    url = input('Enter url:')
    url = 'http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_263475.xml'
    if len(url) < 1 : break
    print ('Retrieving', url)
    uh = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    xmldata = uh.read()
    print ('Retrieved',len(xmldata),'characters')
    pydata = ET.fromstring(xmldata)
    for child in pydata:
        print (child.tag)
    lst = pydata.findall('./comments/comment')
    for comment in lst:
        scount = comment.find('count').text
        intscount = int(scount)
        sumcount = sumcount + intscount
    print('Entries:', len(lst))
    print('Sum:', sumcount)
    if True : break
```